# Remove specific items from a list

Tags: powershell, scripting, conditional-statements

I am creating a script that will help my colleagues to create a new AD user. This is what I have done so far:

```
ipmo activedirectory
$users = import-csv C:\Users\...\Desktop\test_bulk.csv -delimiter ";"
foreach ($User in $users) 
{
    $Displayname = $User.Givenname + " " + $User.Surname
    $Usersurname = $User.Surname
    $Userfirstname = $User.Givenname
    $SAM = $User.Samaccountname
    $OU = $User.path
    $password = $User.Password
    $newuser = New-ADUser -PassThru -Name $Displayname -SamAccountName $SAM -
    GivenName $Userfirstname -Surname $Usersurname -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force)-Enabled $true -Path $OU -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -PasswordNeverExpires $true -OtherAttributes  @{businesscategory="Internal"}
    $gpuser = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User.gpuser | select -ExpandProperty name

    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $newuser -MemberOf $gpuser
}
```

As you can see I have set a variable `$gpuser` so I can output a user's group membership to set all these into the new user's membership.

But there is a little hurdle... I need to remove up to three groups from the retrieved list.
I mean each time I output a user's membership I need to remove a few groups IF they are present in the list.

The thing is I don't know how to script that and where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [`Where-Object`](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) cmdlet and the [`-notin`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) operator.

Basically you will do something like this:

```
$excludeFromThisList = @("group1", "group2")
$newGroupList = $gpuser | Where-Object { $_ -notin $excludeFromThisList }
```